# ¿Cómo guardar un ArrayList para usar sus datos en futuras ejecuciones del programa?

Tags: java, arraylist

Buenos días, estoy acabando mi rudimentario programa de simulación de base de datos de pacientes de hospital. Para poneros en situación os resumo cómo funciona:
Tengo una clase Paciente:

```
public class Paciente {

private String nombre;
private String apell1;
private String apell2;
private int edad;
private String alcohol;
private String fumador;
private int num_expe_clinico;
private String HistorialClinico;`
```

Con ese objeto Paciente, creo un ArrayList:

```
public static ArrayList<Paciente> ArrayPacientes = new ArrayList<Paciente>();
```

Básicamente luego hice una clase principal y desarrollé 4 funciones básicas: insertar paciente, consultar datos de un paciente a partir de su número clinico, borrar paciente y salir del programa.

**¿Qué es lo que necesito?**

Guardar de alguna forma todo lo que guarde mi ArrayPacientes, y al inicio del programa cargar esos datos en mi `ArrayList` de tal forma que los Pacientes que se introduzcan en la primera ejecución del programa, estén disponibles en otras ejecuciones.

Gracias!!

Comment: creo que necesitas usar base de datos, o talves escribir en un texto.txt

Comment: Debes persistir los datos. Ya sea serializando y almacenar en un archivo o guardar directamente en una base de datos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes dos opciones más o menos razonables. Por orden de complejidad:

1. Serialización: Como todos los campos son primitivas o serializables, puedes declarar que tu clase implementa `java.io.Serializable`<sup>1</sup>. `Serializable` marca una clase para que se pueda expresar como un stream de bytes (con `ObjectOutputStream`) y después obtener el objeto original a partir de ese stream(con `ObjectInputStream`). Así que basta guardar esos bytes en un fichero con un `FileOutputStream` y listo.

   Otras opciones similares son serialización como XML o JSON y guardarlo en un fichero, pero aunque no son muy complicadas requiren librerías adicionales.
2. JDBC puro y duro: Creas una BD (puede ser una BD embebida como Derby o HSQLDB, que se ejecutan en la misma JMV), abrir una conexión a la BD y guardar y recuperar elementos mediante sentencias SQL. Con tu ejemplo, lo más normal es que lo organices en una sola tabla con campo para cada campo que sea una primitiva y para Strings.

   Existe una opción que es JPA (mapea automáticamente las clases con tablas de la BD, de forma que no tengas que ocuparte del SQL) pero es más complicado y recomiendo que esperes a estar familiarizado con JDBC.

Comment: sep al final he serializado la clase, y guardado todo en un fichero. Gracias!